# Microsoft Test Manager's interface like for Selenium

Tags: selenium, testing, microsoft-test-manager

Whe are making a proposal to a client for a test automation framework and we are between MTM and Selenium. For what they need (CI process, and manual launch of testing bateryes) is better Selenium.

But in our last meeting the client's head of develop told us that they like the MTM's interface Test Center, because they could unify the automated testing and the manual testing in one interface. So I'm looking for some framework that would provide a similar interface, work with Selenium automated tests and, If possible, interact with their TFS.

Any suggestions?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Why the -1? Is this a silly question?

Comment: I think this question would be better answered on https://sqa.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can't edit anymore so, continuing with my comment... Let's try to summarize your needs. Basically your requirement is a tool/platform which allows you to manage automation tests (so basically code) and manual test case stories / steps etc. right? Then if your client already has Microsoft Stack then going for MTM is probably the best idea cost/time wise. Otherwise you need to evaluate platforms like: QA complete, QTP, Zephyr/Jira etc.. Most of commercial solutions integrate with GIT/TFS/SVN and provide management for both manual and automated cases.